# How to connect MP3 player to TV using RCA?

Tags: audio, tv

I have a personal MP3 player with 3.5mm stereo socket for output.
I have made a 3.5mm to RCA stereo cable by connecting the shorter inputs to the centers of each of the Left and Right RCA jacks and the ground is split up between them.
Even with full volume in the player, I'm unable to hear any sound from the TV speakers in the AV Receiver mode.
How do I get this to work?

Comment: Usually TVs require a video signal to reproduce the audio. If it's not the case, you may need to amplify it, but it's quite strange that you don't get any sound at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:
Disconnect your MP3 player, set TV volume to ca 50%, touch the tip of 3.5 mm jack with finger.
You should hear a plop and possibly a buzz coming from TV speakers.
If not yout TV is not seeing the signal from MP3 player.